# Multiple foreign keys to same table using Elixir

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I am new to ORMs in general. I have a table (lets call it Entity) with columns --

1. ID
2. expression
3. type ( can be 'long_word', 'short_word' or 'sentence' )

Often, the first two types occur in a '`sentence`', so, I want to maintain another table which maps '`Sentences`' to '`long_word`' or '`short_word`' using the '`ID`' field.

All i need is another table with 2 '`Integer fields`' referring to '`ID`' as a foreign key.

But, how do i do this in Elixir?

**Edit :** I was afraid it will come to this eventually. No sweat, SQLAlchemy is solid, it will be worth it in the long run. But i really wish Elixir had worked. Cant have everything the way you want.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: I just spent an hour backporting from Elixir to declarative SQLAlchemy. Elixir might be great, but it was one too many levels of intermingled indirection for me to make sense of.